# Matlab codes for making scales

Tags: matlab

I've extracted certain data from an Excel file.
It involves two columns : one for certain periods and another for corresponing
daily prices. Followings are my codes.(t1 and t2 are user inputs.)

```
row_1 = find(period==t1)
row_2 = find(period==t2)
f_0 = period(row_1:row_2, 1)
f_1 = price(row_1:row_2 , 1) 
y_1 = plot(handles.axes2, f_0, f_1)
```

f_0 : period (x-axis), f_1 : price(y-axis)

My goal is to express the trend of price fluctuations by using sounds.
So the way I came up with this is as follows.
Step1: Find the maximum and minimum value of the price corresponding to the given period. Step2: Divide the distances between these two points into eight sections. Step3: Allocate eight musical scales(C D E F G A B C) to each
eight sections and play it.

At my level, I achieved to find the min/max values of the given period.
But from the next stage, I can't come up with any ideas. 
Please help me with any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to allocate eight musical scales to divided period, and such codes may help.

```
%% let's play some music~
clc; clear;

%% Set the Sampling frequency & time period
fs=44100;
t=0:1/fs:0.5;

%% eight musical scales
Cscale{1}=sin(2*pi*262*t); %c-do
Cscale{2}=sin(2*pi*294*t); %c-re
Cscale{3}=sin(2*pi*330*t); %c-mi
Cscale{4}=sin(2*pi*349*t); %c-fa
Cscale{5}=sin(2*pi*392*t); %c-so
Cscale{6}=sin(2*pi*440*t); %c-la
Cscale{7}=sin(2*pi*494*t); %c-ti
Cscale{8}=sin(2*pi*523*t); %c-do-high
%you could call "sound(Cscale{i},fs)" to paly each scales


%% Divide the distances between these two points
% the highest point must be special treated
Min_p=0;
Max_p=8;
Sample_p=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
for i=1:length(Sample_p)
  S_p=Sample_p(i);
  if (S_p == Max_p)
    sound(Cscale{end},fs);
  else
      %Find the correct music scale and play it
      sound(Cscale{1+floor(8*(Sample_p(i)-Min_p)/(Max_p-Min_p))},fs);
  end
  pause(0.5)
end
```

Here is what I looked at(you may need google translation because it is written in Chinese)

http://blog.csdn.net/weaponsun/article/details/46695255